# Creating pivot table in R

Tags: r, pivot-table, percentage

I know this has been asked numerous times but I've scrolled the internet for the last 2 days and can't find the help I need to create a pivot table or summary table like I could do with excel. I'm completely new to R as in a complete illiterate so I find most examples in R packages help files way too complicated.

I have a list of data ("assemblage") that looks like this

```
Phase   class  NISP
   <chr>   <chr> <int>
1      L    Aves    11
2      L    Fish   128
3      L Mammals    14
4      K    Aves    63
5      K    Fish    30
6      K Mammals   311
7      J    Aves   170
8      J    Fish   327
9      J Mammals   740
10     I    Aves    45
# ... with 18 more rows
```

and I've managed to do a summary/pivottable like table using dcast()

```
pivot <-dcast(assemblage, Phase ~ class, fun.aggregate = sum, value.var = "NISP", margins = TRUE)
```

with the following result

```
Phase Aves Fish Indeterminate Mammals (all)
1      A    1    0             0       6     7
2      B    2    0             0       3     5
3      C   58   20             0     255   333
4      E    5    2             0       5    12
5      F   14    0             0      17    31
6      H  121  154             1     784  1060
7      I   45  110             0     149   304
8      J  170  327             0     740  1237
9      K   63   30             0     311   404
10     L   11  128             0      14   153
11 (all)  490  771             1    2284  3546
```

But what I need now that I can't figure out is:

- replace (all) with "Total"
- order columns in following order ("Phase","Mammals","Fish","Aves","Indeterminate","Total")
- add new columns with percentage of each animal class per phase (percentage of row total).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below should do everything step by step. If anything is unclear, let me know.

```
# make some data
df = data.frame(Phase = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3), 
                Fish = floor(rnorm(5, 150)),
                Mammal = floor(rnorm(5, 50)))

df$all = rowSums(df[, 2:3])

# 1 change name
names(df)[which(names(df) == 'all')] = 'Total'

# 2 - reverse Fish and Mammal
idx1 = 2:3 # columns to change
idx2 = 3:2 # new order of columns
df[, idx1] = df[, idx2]
names(df)[idx1] = names(df)[idx2]

# 3 - calculate percentages
idxT = 2:3 # column indices of interest

newColNames = paste('%', names(df)[idxT])

tmp = df[, idxT, drop = FALSE] / matrix(df["Total"], ncol = length(idxT))
colnames(tmp) = newColNames
df = cbind(df, tmp)
```

Comment: That's great thanks, that does just about everything. There will be a little tidying up to do for importation in Latex but for the moment that's fine.

Comment: Great to hear. If you want to use Latex with APA guidelines, I'd recommend having a look at the R package `xtable`. It has a function `xtable` that takes a matrix or dataframe as argument and returns an APA formatted latex table.